# Preset mouse mode on pyqtgraph widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

my question is simple:
How can I preset the mouse mode in pyqtgraph widget? I would like to have mouse in "1 button mode" all the time. The best solution would be to disable "3 button mode".

Couldn't find any references to this issue on the internet.
Here is a screenshot of what I need to preset:
[image]

What versions am I using:

- Python 3.7.2
- PyQt5

Maybe you're asking yourself why would I like to have it in mouse "button 1 mode" all the time? Well I have the graph widget inside a scrollable window - this causes some really weird interactions - therefore I want to preset the "1 button mode".

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Could it be the [`setMouseMode()`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setMouseMode)?

Comment: I don't have my graph widget inside any class listed in that documentation (PlotItem, Canvas or GraphicsLayout.addViewBox). Therefor I can't call that function.

Comment: Didn't help even if u call the function directly to PlotWidget - it simple does not have the function implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke's answer set me on the right direction.

At the end this is only solution that worked for me (kinda weird):

```
graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
graphWidget.plotItem.getViewBox().setMouseMode(pg.ViewBox.RectMode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [ViewBox.setMouseMode](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setMouseMode). Example:

```
plt = pg.PlotWidget()
plt.vb.setMouseMode(plt.vb.RectMode)
```

Comment: It throws a `NameError: vb`. In my PlotWidget there is no `vb` object unfortunately. I even tried naming it `ViewBox` - didn't help either. Did you tried your solution and did it work?

Comment: Ah, yeah I tried it and then mistranslated it here. Your answer is better, though,